# Regex string where space is optional and trim is followed only by (

Tags: c#, regex, string, trim, regex-greedy

Lets say I have

```
string abc = "and TRIM$ ( 000trim) and (trim000) and  (abctrim) and Trim(trima) and  TRIM (  abc  ) and trim( A) and 0trim"
```

I want only the `TRIM()` Function to change to `RTRIM()` and would want the pattern to ignore the spaces if there are any and consider `(` after the `TRIM`

I am using

```
Regex.Replace(abc, "(?i)([^A-Za-z0-9])TRIM([^A-Za-z0-9][(])", "$1RTRIM(");
```

and the result for above code is

> "and **RTRIM(**   ( 000trim) and (trim000) and  (abctrim) and **Trim**(trimaa) and  **RTRIM(  abc  )** and **trim( A)** and 0trim";

I would want to get output as

> "and **TRIM$** ( 000trim) and (trim000) and  (abctrim) and **RTRIM**(trimaa) and  **RTRIM (  abc  )** and **RTRIM ( A)** and 0trim";

How can I achieve desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\bTRIM(?=\s*\()", "RTRIM", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The regex matches `trim` that is immediatly followed by 0 or more spaces(including tabs) and a opening parenthesis `(`. `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is self-explanatory...

EDIT: add a `(?<![$%])` to make it ignore `trim` with leading `%` or `$` like this :

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\b(?<![$%])TRIM(?=\s*\()", "RTRIM", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: I would use `\bTRIM(?=\s*\()` as the search, just in case there are other instances of RTRIM (or LTRIM) already in the string.

Comment: Regex.Replace(text, @"\bTRIM(?=\s*()", "RTRIM", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) fails when we have "and TRIM$ ( 000trim) and (trim000) and (abctrim) and **$trim(_ef** and (trim and **Trim(changetrim)** and **TRIM ( abc )** and **trim( A)** and 0trim" ........ Output is "and TRIM$ ( 000trim) and (trim000) and (abctrim) and **$trim(_ef** and (trim and **Trim(changetrim)** and **RTRIM( abc )** and **trim( A)** and 0trim"  @Robert McKee

Comment: If the string has  **%trim(_bla)%** it is changing it to **%rtrim(_bla)%**.. how can it be avoided ??  @ Robert McKee

Comment: @virtualreality see my edit for the fix. Next time post a new question, if you decide to change/add requirements after almost a week...

Answer (score 0):

You could do a replace like this:

```
var input = @"and TRIM$ ( 000trim) and (trim000) and  (abctrim) and Trim(trima) and  TRIM (  abc  ) and trim( A) and 0trim";
var pattern = @"(?i)\btrim(?:\s+|)(\([^)]+\))";
string res = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "RTRIM$1");
```